windows: refuses to open a certain file via netrw / ftp (but ok will all others)
I usually don't have any problems opening files with the following line at work (where I don't have admin access) from gvim with:
:e ftp://<myusername>@ftp.<mydomain>.co.uk/path/<FILENAME>
For some reason, this suddenly stopped working for 2 specific files, e.g. ="simple.html", with the terminal window (that I wouldn't usually see at all) getting stuck at:
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c (^(ftp -i -n^) ^< C:\Users\<MYNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp\VHPCA3D.tmp ^>C:\Users\<MYNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp\VNJCA3E.tmp 2^>^&1)
I can see those files
On using vim (not gvim), it also shows:
\\<EXAMPLE>\Users\<INITIAL>\<MYNAME>\app\vim90
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory.

I don't understand what could trigger this problem for 1-2 specific files (which are very small files), but gvim working perfectly ok for all other files? Could a firewall algorithm block specific files on this computer??
(By the way, I have vim installed on the network drive under \\Users<X><MYNAME>\app\vim90\ (in order to have it accessible from any computer at work).
I also installed vim 9.1: problem persists for those two files.
I checked the files (both small), there are regular html files, with regular utf-8 encoding.)
